# copying text with the mouse in VIM, why doesn't it work?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using both MacVim and console Vim.
My shell is ZSH and the terminal is iTerm2.

What I am trying to achieve:

when I'm dealing with the GUI, in other window, sometimes I want a quick copy paste from a VIM window.
I can use the mouse to select the text, but:

- cmd-c doesn't copy
- ctrl-c doesn't copy
- ctrl-shift-c doesn't copy
- right button context menu copies sometimes but not always and I don't know why. I don't know if it's related to the mode I'm in, etc it's just not reliable. At this stage, the menu that appears in the console is not VIM's, since it doesn't have one, but iTerm2, so things get very confusing.

when using MacVim, the menu shows me to use cmd-c to copy, but whether I do it, or using the context menu it sometimes works and, more than often, it doesn't.

Reading from forums, I've tried to do:

> :setmouse=a

but, when I press return it doesn't even acknowledge the line.

So, my simple question is: how can I do quickie copies from a mouse selection in VIM to paste it in another window without have to do anything else that would slow me down?

Answer (score 3):

The command is

```
set mouse=a
```

but you need clipboard interfaces. See `:help "*`

I would visually select (with or without mouse) and use `"*y`, or `:yank *` if it can be done linewise (sometimes the range is easier to type, like `:%y*`).

Alternately, disable mouse-reporting (Cmd-R on mac) and use the native copy-paste.

Comment: i'm looking for a mouse only solution since during these times, I'm not 'in' VIM, I just want to grab part of the text to paste in some other unrelated app quickly, so I don't want to use the keyboard. cmd-r resets the display under iTerm2

Comment: @Thomas sorry, Cmd-R for Terminal.app. Does iTerm not have a shortcut to disable mouse reporting? That said, it’s 3 characters on the keyboard

Comment: it doesn't look like it; there is an option to enable / disable it, but no keyboard toggle. So that I understand: the copy part has to be done outside of VIM, so it is something that has to be solved at the terminal level, is that correct?

Comment: It *can* be, the star-register interfaces with the OS clipboard

Comment: ok, I will read more about this; I'm slowing diving into VIM, still lots to learn :)

Comment: so, if I understand, I can select something (mouse, or 'v'), then do "*y (clipboard then yank) to copy it in the system clipboard? this works in MacVim, but doesn't work from the terminal. Also, I found that in MacVim, in command mode I can select text and do cmd-c but if I am in insert mode it doesn't work. From the terminal session, nothing seems to work.

Comment: just found this: https://evertpot.com/osx-tmux-vim-copy-paste-clipboard/